Union of ordered bases
In Linear Algebra (5th edition) by Friedberg et al., the union of ordered bases is defined in the following way (footnote on page 267):
If $\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots,\beta_k$ are ordered bases for the subspaces $\mathsf{W}_1,\mathsf{W}_2,\dots,\mathsf{W}_n$ of $\mathsf{V}$, respectively, then $\beta_1\cup\beta_2\cup\cdots\cup\beta_k$ is an ordered set, where the vectors in $\beta_1$ are listed first (in the same order as in $\beta_1$), then the vectors in $\beta_2$ (in the same order as in $\beta_2$), etc.
This definition does not (in my opinion) imply that $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_k$ are pairwise disjoint.
Then Theorem 5.9 says that, if $\mathsf{W}_1,\mathsf{W}_2,\dots,\mathsf{W}_n$ are subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space $\mathsf{V}$, then the following two statements are equivalent.
(a) $\mathsf{V}=\mathsf{W}_1\oplus\mathsf{W}_2\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathsf{W}_k$.
(e) For each $i=1,2,\dots,k$, there exists an ordered basis $\gamma_i$ for $\mathsf{W}_i$ such that $\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2\cup\cdots\cup\gamma_k$ is an ordered basis for $\mathsf{V}$.
(a)$\implies$(e) is obvious, but the converse not so much, unless the union of ordered bases contains the implicit assumption that the ordered bases are pairwise disjoint. If we regard the union in the usual set theory way, (e) does not imply (a).
For example, let $\mathsf{V}=\mathsf{R}^3$, $\mathsf{W}_1$ be the $xy$-plane, $\mathsf{W}_2$ be the $yz$-plane, $\gamma_1=\{(1,1,0),(0,1,0)\}$, $\gamma_2=\{(0,1,0),(0,1,1)\}$. Then $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are ordered bases for $\mathsf{W}_1$ and $\mathsf{W}_2$, respectively. If we do the union in the usual set theory way, we have $\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2=\{(1,1,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,1)\}$, which is an ordered basis for $\mathsf{V}$, so (e) holds. If the theorem is to be believed, we would have $\mathsf{V}=\mathsf{W}_1\oplus\mathsf{W}_2$ which is obviously false.
But if we assume $\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_k$ are pairwise disjoint, then (e) would indeed imply (a). (The details is omitted here.)
I am wondering what is everyone's opinion on this. Am I interpreting everything correctly?

As I recall, when  Friedberg talks about "ordered lists" (including ordered bases) they allow repetitions, so you should interpret the union as allowing for repetitions, given that the order would make any vector that occurs more then once occupy two distinct places in the order.

@ArturoMagidin If we allow repetition, then the example in my description would not make any sense......

It would, in that in your example you would not have a basis (a list with repeated vectors is not linearly independent) so you would reach the correct conclusion.
